# override file property with script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to change a value inside yaml file

e.g. yaml

```
...
metadata:
  name: appname
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: %APP_NAME%
```

Now I tried with the following

`sed -i 's/%APP_NAME%/newappname/g' app.yaml`

And I got error:

`sed: 1: "app.yaml": extra characters at the end of d command`

Im not sure how to overcome this, what I need it to override the file value and not just to see it as output

at the end the file should look like

```
...
metadata:
  name: appname
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: newappname
```

If I remove the `-i` from the command I was able to see the output as requested however I need to override the file value and not just to see the output

Comment: Please add version of `sed` to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus - I tried `sed -V` and `sed --version` but got an error `sed: illegal option -- -
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...] ...`

Comment: You have BSD version of sed most probably.

Comment: @rid - now it works, however it create a file with extension `yaml.bak` , is there a way to remove (or just avoid it)  it with inline command or just `rm file` ? btw you can add it as answer

Comment: @BenoOdr, not that I can tell (BSD `sed` is a bit more limited than GNU `sed`). You can either not have a backup (the not recommended option), or remove the backup with `rm`.

Comment: @BenoOdr, also, I suspect you're on a Mac. If so, you could `brew install gnu-sed` then use `gsed` instead of `sed` if you'd like to use the GNU version instead of the BSD version that comes with the Mac. If you want this to be part of a portable script however, it might be better to stick to the common characteristics of both `sed`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some versions of `sed` require the argument to `-i`, while on others it's optional.

Try:

```
sed -i .bak 's/%APP_NAME%/newappname/g' app.yaml
```

or `sed -i '' ...` if you don't want to create any backup (not recommended, see the sed manual about this).